Modifying CV template to include picture
I would like to modify this CV template in order to make room for a photo in the top left or top right of the document (probably top left would look best). I would be very grateful for any pointers. This is the relevant part of the code:
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\reversemarginpar % Move the margin to the left of the page 

\newcommand{\MarginText}[1]{\marginpar{\raggedleft\itshape\small#1}} % New command defining the margin text style

\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis} % Use the classicthesis style for the style of the document
\usepackage[LabelsAligned]{currvita} % Use the currvita style for the layout of the document

\renewcommand{\cvheadingfont}{\LARGE\color{Maroon}} % Font color of your name at the top

\usepackage{hyperref} % Required for adding links   and customizing them
\hypersetup{colorlinks, breaklinks, urlcolor=Maroon, linkcolor=Maroon} % Set link colors

\newlength{\datebox}\settowidth{\datebox}{Spring 2011} % Set the width of the date box in each block

\newcommand{\NewEntry}[3]{\noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0 \parbox{\datebox}{\small \textit{#1}}\hspace{1.5em} #2 #3 % Define a command for each new block - change spacing and font sizes here: #1 is the left margin, #2 is the italic date field and #3 is the position/employer/location field
\vspace{0.5em}} % Add some white space after each new entry

\newcommand{\Description}[1]{\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0\noindent\raggedright\footnotesize{#1}\par\normalsize\vspace{1em}} % Define a command for descriptions of each entry - change spacing and font sizes here

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty} % Stop the page count at the bottom of the first page

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{cv}{\spacedallcaps{John Smith}}\vspace{1.5em} % Your name

\noindent\spacedlowsmallcaps{Personal Information}\vspace{0.5em} % Personal information heading

\NewEntry{}{\textit{Born in Canada,}}{20 November 1987} % Birthplace and date

\NewEntry{email}{\href{mailto:john@smith.com}{john@smith.com}} % Email address

\NewEntry{website}{\href{http://www.johnsmith.com}{http://www.johnsmith.com}} % Personal website

\NewEntry{phone}{(H) +1 (000) 111 1111\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ (M) +1 (000) 111 1112} % Phone number(s)

\vspace{1em} % Extra white space between the personal information section and goal

\noindent\spacedlowsmallcaps{Goal}\vspace{1em} % Goal heading, could be used for a quotation or short profile instead

\Description{Gain fundamental experience in my area of interest and expertise.}\vspace{2em} % Goal text

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   WORK EXPERIENCE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\noindent\spacedlowsmallcaps{Work Experience}\vspace{1em}

\NewEntry{2012--Present}{1\textsuperscript{st} Year Analyst, \textsc{Lehman Brothers}}

\Description{\MarginText{Lehman Brothers}Developed spreadsheets for risk analysis on exotic derivatives on a wide array of commodities (ags, oils, precious and base metals), managed blotter and secondary trades on structured notes, liaised with Middle Office, Sales and Structuring for bookkeeping. \\ Reference: John \textsc{McDonald}\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ +1 (000) 111 1111\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ \href{mailto:john@lehman.com}{john@lehman.com}}

%------------------------------------------------

\end{cv}

\end{document}

and this is what it looks like without photo. I can give up one of the two phone numbers and write the date of birth more compactly to make room on the right side, although probably a photo on the left side would look best. I accept advice on this.

(1) Add \usepackage{graphicx} to the preamble.
(2) Have MyPhoto.jpg in your working directory.
(3) Use \begin{cv}{\MarginText{\includegraphics[width=\oddsidemargin]{MyPhoto}}\spacedallcaps{John Smith}}\vspace{1.5em}  to display the photo at the top left of the document (Right-aligned in margin space).

\documentclass{scrartcl}

\reversemarginpar % Move the margin to the left of the page 

\newcommand{\MarginText}[1]{\marginpar{\raggedleft\itshape\small#1}} % New command defining the margin text style

\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis} % Use the classicthesis style for the style of the document
\usepackage[LabelsAligned]{currvita} % Use the currvita style for the layout of the document

\usepackage{graphicx} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\renewcommand{\cvheadingfont}{\LARGE\color{Maroon}} % Font color of your name at the top

\usepackage{hyperref} % Required for adding links   and customizing them
\hypersetup{colorlinks, breaklinks, urlcolor=Maroon, linkcolor=Maroon} % Set link colors

\newlength{\datebox}\settowidth{\datebox}{Spring 2011} % Set the width of the date box in each block

\newcommand{\NewEntry}[3]{\noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0 \parbox{\datebox}{\small \textit{#1}}\hspace{1.5em} #2 #3 % Define a command for each new block - change spacing and font sizes here: #1 is the left margin, #2 is the italic date field and #3 is the position/employer/location field
    \vspace{0.5em}} % Add some white space after each new entry

\newcommand{\Description}[1]{\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0\noindent\raggedright\footnotesize{#1}\par\normalsize\vspace{1em}} % Define a command for descriptions of each entry - change spacing and font sizes here

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
    
    \thispagestyle{empty} % Stop the page count at the bottom of the first page
    
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %   NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION SECTION
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    \begin{cv}{\MarginText{\includegraphics[width=\oddsidemargin]{MyPhoto}}\spacedallcaps{John Smith}}\vspace{1.5em} % Your name CHANGED <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        
        \noindent\spacedlowsmallcaps{Personal Information}\vspace{0.5em} % Personal information heading
        
        \NewEntry{}{\textit{Born in Canada,}}{20 November 1987} % Birthplace and date
        
        \NewEntry{email}{\href{mailto:john@smith.com}{john@smith.com}} % Email address
        
        \NewEntry{website}{\href{http://www.johnsmith.com}{http://www.johnsmith.com}} % Personal website
        
        \NewEntry{phone}{(H) +1 (000) 111 1111\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ (M) +1 (000) 111 1112} % Phone number(s)
        
        \vspace{1em} % Extra white space between the personal information section and goal
        
        \noindent\spacedlowsmallcaps{Goal}\vspace{1em} % Goal heading, could be used for a quotation or short profile instead
        
        \Description{Gain fundamental experience in my area of interest and expertise.}\vspace{2em} % Goal text
        
        %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        %   WORK EXPERIENCE
        %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        
        \noindent\spacedlowsmallcaps{Work Experience}\vspace{1em}
        
        \NewEntry{2012--Present}{1\textsuperscript{st} Year Analyst, \textsc{Lehman Brothers}}
        
        \Description{\MarginText{Lehman Brothers}Developed spreadsheets for risk analysis on exotic derivatives on a wide array of commodities (ags, oils, precious and base metals), managed blotter and secondary trades on structured notes, liaised with Middle Office, Sales and Structuring for bookkeeping. \\ Reference: John \textsc{McDonald}\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ +1 (000) 111 1111\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ \href{mailto:john@lehman.com}{john@lehman.com}}
        
        %------------------------------------------------
        
    \end{cv}
    
\end{document}

MyPhoto.jpg


Thanks a lot. Is there a way to make the margin space bigger (in the whole page, so that it doesn't look like patchwork) in case I want the photo to be slightly bigger?

@Karl For example using `\includegraphics[width=1.3\oddsidemargin]{MyPhoto} will enlarge the photo.

Is there anyway to include a photo that is shaped as a circle? If I do this normally I get a square photo with the difference surface colored in black
